# Valid parameters for astype in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I'm new to NumPy and SciPy.
Unlike Matlab, it seems like there is a data type associated with each array in NumPy.

Suppose that we have an integer array `x`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

If I want to convert the array into float, then it seems like the following works:

```
y1 = x.astype('float64')  # Works!
y2 = x.astype('float_')   # Works!
y3 = x.astype('float')    # Works!
```

But I'm somewhat puzzled to see the following also works without the single quotation marks.

```
y4 = x.astype(float)      # Still works!!
```

But for other expressions used for y1 and y2, if I omit the single quotation mark, it doesn't work:

```
y5 = x.astype(float64)  # Doesn't work.
y6 = x.astype(float_)   # Doesn't work.
```

So, I'm somewhat confused about why y4 works, but y5 and y6 cause an error. Could someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: I haven't used Matlab, but [judging by the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html), it looks like Matlab arrays have dtypes too. They just always default to double-precision floating point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other expressions work, you just need to import the types from numpy. You don't need to do this for `float` because it is a built-in type for Python.

```py
y5 = x.astype(np.float64)
y6 = x.astype(np.float_)
```

Both the string-type and type-type inputs are converted to a `numpy.dtype` object internally, which is what you see when using the `ndarray.dtype` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

These 2 don't work because there isn't, in your workspace, variables with those names:

```
y5 = x.astype(float64)  # Doesn't work.
y6 = x.astype(float_)   # Doesn't work.
```

I get a `NameError: name 'float64' is not defined`.  The error is produced by the Python interpreter, before anything is passed to the `x.astype` method.

You'd get the same error if you just typed `float64` in the interactive interpreter.

`np.float64` does work because there is such a variable in the `np` namespace.  It is actually a numpy class.

`float` also works.  It too is a class, a base Python one (it can also be used as a function, converting a string or number to a float object).

'float64' is a string, that `astype` understands, probably by looking up something in a table.  (I could look that up).

On the other hand if I give `astype` something random string I get a different error

```
In [967]: A.astype('bar')
...
TypeError: data type "bar" not understood
```

`np.dtype('bar')` gives the same error.

```
np.dtype(float)
np.dtype('float64')
np.dtype('float')
```

all return the same `dtype('float64')` object.

Answer (score 1):

reading the documentation of `astype`:

```
dtype : str or dtype
    Typecode or data-type to which the array is cast.
```

When you're using `float` without quotes, then you're using dtype.
When you're using `"float"`, then you're using str.

`float64` and `float_`aren't dtypes in python.